# How to remove child Thumbnails from DeckView?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recents

I want to reuse Android Lollipop recent style library from [vikramkakkar](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/DeckView)

I want to show only header bars stack with no thumbnails (app screenshots) attached to each one of it. How can I remove child thumbnails? Is there direct API to achieve this from library?.

**Code**

```
DeckChildViewThumbnail deckChildViewThumbnail = (DeckChildViewThumbnail) weakView.get().findViewById(R.id.task_view_thumbnail); 
deckChildViewThumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Would you please show us some code you already have / which is not giving the desired result?

Comment: I am using DeckChildViewThumbnail deckChildViewThumbnail = (DeckChildViewThumbnail) weakView.get().findViewById(R.id.task_view_thumbnail);
 deckChildViewThumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);